# HTTPS node js, express can not be changed to green?

Tags: node.js, ssl

I'm trying to change the lock from HTTPS on my localhost from red to green....

```
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');
var app = require('express')();
var options = {
   key: fs.readFileSync('privatekey.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('certificate.pem')
};

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.send('Hello World!');
});

https.createServer(options, app).listen(3000, function () {
   console.log('Started!');
});
```

I get the following error in my browser

> This page is insecure (broken HTTPS). Certificate Error There are issues with the site's certificate chain (net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID)

I used OpenSSL to create the certificates.  I don't know what more to do with the certificates

Comment: Why does your browser say it's red?  Is the certificate signed by a trusted root certificate authority?  What's the hostname you're using to access it?  You won't be able to get a certificate for `localhost`.  You could always take your self-signed certificate and import it on your system.

Comment: This page is insecure (broken HTTPS).
Certificate Error
There are issues with the site's certificate chain (net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID).

Comment: Yeah, so that means it's self-signed.  Import it on your system if you're just testing.  On Windows, just double-click it and add it to trusted root certificates.

Comment: i did it, and didnt work...

Comment: Did you restart Chrome?

Comment: Then, you probably didn't import the right thing into the right place.  Be sure it's the certificate you're importing.

Answer (score 0):

You've created self-signed certificates which the OS needs to be told are valid before your browser will allow them. You need to add them to Keychain on a mac or the trusted root certificates. In both cases, double clicking the `pem` file should bring up the appropriate application at which point you can mark the certificates as trusted.

https://www.digicert.com/csr-creation-ssl-installation-mac-osx-el-capitan.htm

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sbs/2008/05/08/installing-a-self-signed-certificate-as-a-trusted-root-ca-in-windows-vista/

Comment: Thanks, i already did it in windows but didnt get the Security Warning, the lock still red even if i added the certificate on the trusted root certificate...

Comment: Be sure to restart your computer and your browser.